# How myPreparedStmt.setString for Regexp Sql in Java?

Tags: java

I have a table with text colum & I want to search all rows containing a word

```
  String sql="Select text from MyTable where text REGEXP '[[:<:]]?[[:>:]]'
  myPreparedStmt=myCon.prepareStatement(sql);
  myPreparedStmt.setString( 1, word); //---> this line has an error "SQL Exception:  No parameters defined during prepareCall()"
```

If I run the following query, then it will be fine but this is risky cos hacker can inject bad script:

```
  String sql="Select text from MyTable where text REGEXP '[[:<:]]"+word+"[[:>:]]'
  myPreparedStmt=myCon.prepareStatement(sql);
```

So How myPreparedStmt.setString for Regexp Sql in Java?

Comment: What are you doing _after_ `setString`?

Comment: simple: ResultSet results=myPreparedStmt.executeQuery();

Comment: Ah I see your problem. See my answer.

Comment: Btw I noticed your *Java strings* in the question don't end with `";`. Hope it's just something you missed out in the question, not your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `sql="Select text from MyTable where text REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', ?, '[[:>:]]')` or add the Regex stuff in Java:

```
String sql = "Select text from MyTable where text REGEXP ?";
myPreparedStmt = myCon.prepareStatement(sql);
myPreparedStmt.setString(1, "[[:<:]]" + word + "[[:>:]]");
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, you're placing the question mark `?` inside the *SQL string* (the string inside an SQL statement enclosed between two single quotes `'`).

Change it to:

```
String sql="Select text from MyTable where text REGEXP '[[:<:]]'||?||'[[:>:]]'";
```

Or:

```
String sql="Select text from MyTable where text REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]',?,'[[:>:]]')";
```

*PS: Your database might not support the `CONCAT` function. Also in PostgreSQL, the `||` will need all strings to be not `NULL` (or the output will be `NULL`), while the `CONCAT` can concatenate `NULL` strings as empty strings.*